# Qt 5.8 база данных

Tags: база-данных, qt5, qtcreator

Есть ли способ создать приложение на QT, чтобы база данных была внутри exe-файла, то есть как-бы "портативное" приложение, а не отдельно файл базы и exe приложения для работы с ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практически все примеры в поставке с базами данных содержат именно такое решение - базу данных "в памяти". Вот, например, фрагмент кода из проекта примера **relationaltablemodel**:

```
  void createRelationalTables()
  {
      QSqlQuery query;
      query.exec("create table employee(id int primary key, name varchar(20), city int, country int)");
      query.exec("insert into employee values(1, 'Espen', 5000, 47)");
      query.exec("insert into employee values(2, 'Harald', 80000, 49)");
      query.exec("insert into employee values(3, 'Sam', 100, 1)");

      query.exec("create table city(id int, name varchar(20))");
      query.exec("insert into city values(100, 'San Jose')");
      query.exec("insert into city values(5000, 'Oslo')");
      query.exec("insert into city values(80000, 'Munich')");

      query.exec("create table country(id int, name varchar(20))");
      query.exec("insert into country values(1, 'USA')");
      query.exec("insert into country values(47, 'Norway')");
      query.exec("insert into country values(49, 'Germany')");
  }
```

Весь код примера можно найти [здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-relationaltablemodel-example.html)

Другой вопрос - зачем, если вы используете встроенные данные, без возможности их сохранения при следующей загрузки программы, то не лучше ли использовать стандартные контейнеры: QMap, QVector, QList, QSet, или их std и boost аналоги или простые массивы C++?

Comment: А есть способ сохранения при следующем запуске программы используя встроенные данные?

Comment: @Анатолий По вашему exe-файл должен записывать сам в себя? Так делают только вирусы. Чтобы сохранял данные нужен внешний файл. Можно, конечно, использовать "встроенную" базу, и использовать внешний файл в "своем" формате (у меня фантазии не хватает, для чего это может понадобится), но проще использовать "нормальную" базу данных с оответствующим драйвером.